# Change endpoint for OpenFaaS function

Tags: openfaas

By default, functions deployed to [OpenFaaS](https://www.openfaas.com/) are available at one of the following endpoints:

1. `http://$IP:8080/function/[function_name]`
2. `http://$IP:8080/async-function/[function_name]`

How can I create an endpoint like the following?

`http://[my_domain]/api/v1/[function_name]`

Answer (score 1):

How are you running OpenFaas? Assuming you are running in Kubernetes, you'll need an Ingress for your functions (so that they can be accessible outside your cluster).

There are a bunch of Ingress options:

1. Follow Alex's example [here](https://blog.alexellis.io/tls-the-easy-way-with-openfaas-and-k3sup/), this is end-to-end, which I found very helpful.
2. Use the [openfaas ingress operator](https://docs.openfaas.com/reference/ssl/kubernetes-with-cert-manager/#deploy-the-ingressoperator). More detail [here](https://github.com/openfaas-incubator/ingress-operator).
3. [Use an API Gateway like Kong](https://kylosmcgraff.com/hmac-auth-with-kong-in-kubernetes/), which is what I do. Kong is super flexible. This sample shows you how to use HMAC, but also has links to configuring JWT.
4. Use another [supported OpenFaas Ingress](https://docs.openfaas.com/reference/ssl/kubernetes-with-cert-manager/#use-zalandos-skipper-ingresscontroller); I have not tried these.

If you are not running in Kubernetes, let me know, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: For sandbox development, I'm using faasd. For production, I was planning on using Kubernetes.